# Is there a performance or encapsulation reason to create a private variable to use in place of a public property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, properties

Let's say I have a class with a public property used for property injection, like this:

```
public partial class ManageFoo : PageBase
{
    [Inject]
    public IFoo Foo { get; set; }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        this.Foo.Bar();
    }
}
```

Our IoC container handles injecting an instance of `IFoo` into the property. As you can see the property `Foo` uses the short hand `{ get; set; }` to define the property. However I have heard it is bad practice to use the public property throughout the class and I should have an accompanying private variable like this:

```
public partial class ManageFoo : PageBase
{
    [Inject]
    public IFoo Foo
    {
        get { return _foo; }
        set { _foo = value; }
    }

    private IFoo _foo;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        _foo.Bar();
    }
}
```

I've heard differing opinions but I've yet to hear some concrete reasons why one is better than another. Is the shorter syntax preferred or is the private variable preferred, and why?

Comment: I'm not sure a "should you" question belongs on SO. I think it belongs on Programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Where did you hear that it's bad practice?

Comment: @Gabe, happy? @John A colleague. He didn't have a good reason why, hence the question.

Comment: @Chevex: why pay any attention to someone who doesn't have a reason?

Comment: @John because he is looking over my shoulder and criticizing my code. Now I have something to show him from numerous different people.

Comment: @Chevex: You can tell him to take it up with the Skeet at this point :)  Honestly though, I'm trying to think of a compelling reason to take your colleague's position and I just can't.  Maybe he thinks the internals of the class shouldn't access its externals because the latter might change?  It would be a breaking change, so the internals are the least of the worries there.  Maybe he thinks the property can have logic added to it that you don't want to use internally?  Case-by-case basis, but generally I'd disagree that any accessor logic should only "sometimes" be used.

Comment: @David that's what I figured, but I wanted to get my ducks in a row before I argue. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no significant difference between using an automatically-implemented property and using the explicit form. Yes, your class's code will all go through the property - which is almost certainly going to be inlined by the JIT.

The automatically implemented property gives you less code, and it's clearer - go for it. Next time someone tells you it's bad practice to refer to a public property within the class that declares it, ask for concrete examples of how it can be harmful :)

Comment: Well that's basically what I was doing just now (asking for examples of how it can be harmful) so that I have something to refer to when I tell him he is wrong. You have all answered my question quite well. Thank you.

Comment: @Cbevex: Be more forthright than that: if someone is claiming you should use more complicated code, *they* should be providing the concrete arguments in favour of changing.

Comment: In a perfect world, yes. But when they happen to be higher on the salary chain then one can get stuck with the unfortunate task of defending his position regardless of who made the claim.

Answer (score 3):

Private variable doesn't add any value in the code its redundant. the generated IL for both are equivalent except for your method call which now depends on the private member and by passes the property getter.

Best code is no code or at least less code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the { get; set; } is syntactic sugar for a backing-private the compiler creates for you. In effect, calling the public property accesses that private variable either way.

Now if the public property was overridable and you were concerned about encapsulation, I can certainly see why you might want to define and use your own private. But in general, I don't think it really matters and I prefer to call the property.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and concise answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm simply too lazy to add a private property when it's not necessary.

I guess its up to standards you set for your application cause it all ends up the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you use ILDASM to look at the Intermediate language that is generated when C# is 'compiled' you will see that the use of

```
public IFoo Foo { get; set; }
```

causes the C# compiler to create the holding private variable for you.

if the only access to Foo will be through the property then there is no need to add a private place holder. If, however, any other property or method can change the result of obj.Foo then a private variable is in order.

Answer (score 1):

Further to what others have said, referencing the private backing field in your class makes modifying the class itself more difficult. For example, imagine that you wanted the setter to do something other than just set the backing field (raise an event, for example). Or you decide to use some type of lazy evaluation on get. If your implementation references the backing field throughout, then making those modifications is much more difficult than if the implementation always references the public property.

When auto-implemented properties were introduced, I did some testing to see if there was any difference in performance. There was none. Accessing an auto-implemented property executes just as fast as accessing the backing field of a property implemented in the old way. My conclusion: use auto-implemented properties whenever possible because it's less code, easier to modify, and there's no performance penalty.

Answer (score 1):

There are some few limitations when using automated property:

- You can not declare a property with just a get or a set;
- You can not assign an initial value;
- you can not add more logic to the getting and the setting of the value;

Answer (score 1):

One of the main reasens for using properties at all (instead of public fields) is that you can add in validation at a later date. If your college makes a habit out of accessing the private backing field directly then you might have a headacke when you add some validation which is promptly ignored. That can be a tricky bug to catch.